# Reading sendFormParameters params for JS Adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I have javascript WLResourceRequest.POST call at client side. I'm trying to read the received values at server end. On the server side I can to read only "AB".

Client side code:

```
var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest("/adapters/AdapterNewGet/getFeed", WLResourceRequest.POST);
var formParameters={"params":"['AB','CD','EF']")};   
resourceRequest.sendFormParameters(formParameters).then(app.onSuccess, app.onFailure);
```

Adapter Side code:

```
function getFeed(tag) {
    var input = {
        method : 'get',
        returnedContentType : 'xml',
        path : getPath(tag)
    };
    return MFP.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}
```

Here, when I print `JSON.stringify(tag)`, it prints only "AB". 
Please let me know the way to access all passed values from client code.

Comment: You're using `post` but then `get`? What's with this mixing? Also, you have an extra ")" at the end of the value for `formParameters`.

Comment: Its not working even after removing ")". Consider Adapter Side code:

function getFeed(tag) {
    return {"Value":"param="+tag[1]};          //prints param=B
}

Comment: Its not working even after removing ")". Consider Adapter Side code:

function getFeed(tag) {
    return {"Value":"param="+tag[1]};      //prints param=B and tag[0]="A"
}                                                                                                              
 In MobileFirst Swagger, I can see request url for "params" ['AB','CD',''EF] as follows: http://localhost:9080/mfp/api/adapters/TestAdapter/getFeed?params=%5B'AB'%2C'CD'%2C'EF'%5D

Comment: In your JS adapter procedure: can you change it to the following patter:
function getFeed(arg1,arg2,arg3) and then obtain the params

Comment: Enhancing grammar

Answer (score 0):

For Javascript adapter, you need to modify your procedure's method signature to include the parameters you are sending.

For

```
var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest("/adapters/AdapterNewGet/getFeed", WLResourceRequest.POST);
var formParameters={"params":"['AB','CD','EF']")};   
resourceRequest.sendFormParameters(formParameters).then(app.onSuccess, app.onFailure);
```

in your client code, change the Javascript adapter to :

```
function getFeed(arg1,arg2,arg3) {

  MFP.Loggerinfo(arg1);
  MFP.Loggerinfo(arg2);
  MFP.Loggerinfo(arg3);
  .....

  return MFP.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}
```