# Reading received sendFormParameters params into JS Adapter method in IBM MobileFirst Platform v8.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-cli, mobilefirst-studio

I have javascript `WLResourceRequest.POST` call at client side and trying to read the received values at server end. At server, I am able to read only "AB".

Client side code:

```js
var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest("/adapters/AdapterNewGet/getFeed", WLResourceRequest.POST);
var formParameters={"params":"['AB','CD','EF']"};   
resourceRequest.sendFormParameters(formParameters).then(app.onSuccess, app.onFailure);
```

Adapter Side code:

```js
function getFeed(tag) {
    var input = {
        method : 'post',
        returnedContentType : 'xml',
        path : getPath(tag)
    };
    return MFP.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}
```

Here, when I print `JSON.stringify(tag)`, it prints only "AB". Please let me know the way to access all passed values from client code into adapter method `getFeed(tag)`.

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading received sendFormParameters params for JS Adapter method in IBM MobileFirst Platform v8.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43287348/reading-received-sendformparameters-params-for-js-adapter-method-in-ibm-mobilefi)

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion that was pointed out to me was

```
var params =['hello','world'];                                         
 var newParams = {'params' : JSON.stringify(params)};                   
 resourceRequest.sendFormParameters(newParams).then(.....)
```

and in the JS adapter , define the function accordingly:

```
function getFeed(x,y) {                                                 

 WL.Logger.error(JSON.stringify(x));                                    
 WL.Logger.error(JSON.stringify(y));
```

This means on the receiving end, you need to specify the number of parameters on the function call matching the number of parameters set on the client (2 here)

This might not work if the number of values you are passing varies on the client